# unable to uninstall python3.5 on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, uninstallation

When I tried to remove python3.5 on ubuntu, it always reports error

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-commandnotfound : Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 1.5.4-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-software-properties : Depends: unattended-upgrades but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

In this case, I tried to reinstall the dependence, but finally, it always reports like

```
python3-commandnotfound : Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 1.5.4-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

I also tried apt-get remove/reinstall/autoremove/update/upgrade, but it deosn't work. I can see the same error finally. The dependence file is not going to be installed.
It looks I'm in a dead loop. How can I remove everything manually?

Comment: Fixed by apt-get -f install